# Keeping elements position while resizing browser windows/ resolution

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, positioning

Basically i'm using a background(body) and i need certain elements to be positioned exactly where i want them to be(i used top/left %) (usually images and tables, but in this example i have used simple div elements); after resizing the browser window/ changing the resolution the elements are of course moving  accordingly to the new size, hence they change position. I tried using a div parent to solve that, but i failed.
HTML & CSS :

```css
body
{
background:black;
}
#content
{
    background:blue;
    top:1%;
    position:relative;
    height:900px;
    max-width:1600px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.a
{
position:absolute;
background:yellow;
height:600px;
width:800px;
top:15%;
left:5%;
}

.b
{
background:red;
height:100px;
width:100px;
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

<div class="a">
Box1
</div>

<div class="b">
Box2
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you use a percentage value to layout where an item is on the page, of course your image will move so it stays that % away from whatever it is being measured against. What is your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the values to px rather than %
this would be helpful
the values are not exact, just for depiction

```css
body
{
background:black;
}
#content
{
    background:blue;
    top:9px;
    position:relative;
    height:900px;
    max-width:1600px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.a
{
position:absolute;
background:yellow;
height:600px;
width:800px;
top:150px;
left:50px;
}

.b
{
background:red;
height:100px;
width:100px;
position:absolute;
top:50px;
left:80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

<div class="a">
Box1
</div>

<div class="b">
Box2
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: So the only thing you changed was % to px?(if i'm not seeing right). The thing is, if i put something like top:500px;
left:1400px; to the red one, it will be ok on full screen, but awful minimized.As you can see in yours, the yellow box already ran over the limit of the parent div(blue)

Comment: Yes, values from % to px. because % works in respect to screen resolution

Comment: Yes, thats true, and you should not provide the values of height and width in px. those aren't responsive. and what really are you trying to accomplish

Comment: As i said below to another person, "Moving them according to resolution would be a solution too, but how can i move them only after the resolution changed? Let's say i have the big yellow box left->small red box to its right. That would be in full window mode. After resizing it to<=half, the red box to be moved below the yellow box, not INTO it as i coded.". I designed something that "works" in a full windowed browser. If i change that windows size, it's a hoax. Elements get over others and so one. I need them to change the position as i want after resizing the window.

Comment: In that case consider using [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) read this patiently and complete and surely you will be able to solve your issue. I could write you a code in 20mins but that wont help you. Go through this article and you will be doing this by yourself in one hour

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try today and actually get back here to let you know the result.

Comment: Sure !! Go for it. All the best.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/WQuHkiZG  @Joykal Infotech The explanation is there. As long as i let the default :static position it's all good, but i can't get it to work with my own.

Comment: [link](https://pastebin.com/Xeua5QSn) This is the closest i've got to it. Coding in cases by resolution.

Comment: Have a look at it.
[link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: use can use grid-area for the container and define the no of columns leaving  the space in between, now you can place particular single item with grid column-start and row-start and the same process you can define the grid in media query and the placement of the buttons.